# Double click on a cell shows other sheet filter with cell content

Tags: excel, vba, double-click, autofilter

I am working on a intuitive BOM.
In my sheet1 I have the complete list of parts used into assemblies (C contains all references)
In my sheet2 I have the list of assemblies done with all parts.
Column A are the references of assemblies, then G2:X10000 (table can increase) contains all part references (each row is the BOM of an assembly)

I want to double click on a part reference in sheet 2 (G2:X10000) and to switch automatically to sheet1 with as filter for column C the reference of double clicked cell.

I tried some codes already but always returning errors even adapting to my case.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
        If ActiveCell.Column = 1 Then
        Feuil1.ListObjects("Components_table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value.
    Feuil1.Activate
        End If
    End Sub
```

Here Feuil1 is my sheet1 with "Components_table" a name I gave to the component table (apparently it was needed with this code). Here I tried the code only with double click activated on a test sheet in first column before placing the code in my sheet2.
There is always an error with the line "Feuil1.ListObjects....", as is I have "execution error 9" message.

Could you help me finding a specific code for my application?

Thank you

Comment: [Worksheet.BeforeDoubleClick](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.worksheet.beforedoubleclick).

Comment: What do you have working so far?  Which part is broken?  *How* is it broken — what does/doesn't it do, what error messages do you get?  Is it the double-clicking that fails?  Is it the filter that fails?  Break your code down into small sections, and test them like that!

Comment: Ok sorry I should have written tested codes, I edit the topic

Comment: Is that final full-stop in the erring line (`Criteria1:=ActiveCell.Value.`) a typo copying it over, or is it there in the code you are trying to run?

Comment: Looks like a mistake I did copying the code to stack overflow, sorry !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(ByVal Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    If Target.Column = 1 Then
        Feuil1.ListObjects("Components_table").Range.AutoFilter Field:=3, Criteria1:=Target.Value
        Feuil1.Activate
        Cancel = True
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you for the proposal, but I still have this Error 9, maybe does it come from my Components_table not well defined?
The message is "Index does not belong to selection" (translated to english)
If there is a way to not use the table name it would be even better (at the and "Components_table" = Components!$A:$AD)

Comment: Check your table name matches exactly and what range it is set to. "Index does not belong to selection" suggests to me that `Field = 3` i.e. choose the 3rd column, does not fit the table size?

Comment: I am sure the reference I double click is the same as in the table (I copy/paste for the trial). The cell I double click is in Column A, the reference to look for is in "Components" at column C (so I guess Field = 3 is correct, right?)

Comment: What do you get if you enter `?Feuil1.ListObjects("Components_table").Range.Address` into the immediate window?

Comment: I have exactly the same error (nb 9)... Maybe I named Components_table with a wrong method ?
To do so I went to Formulas → Define a name

Comment: Ah. You're creating a named range. Instead, you want to convert the range to a list (table) : Insert > Table

Comment: Ok great ! So then I have $A:$AD as answer in immediate window and the code is running well ! thanks a lot.
If I want the Target.Column to apply from G to X, do I have to copy the code or is there a way to do it in one row ?

Comment: `If Target.Column >=7 and Target.Column <=24 Then` where G is 7th column and X is 24th